# HTML5 elements not saving on my domain

Tags: css, html

I have some `HTML5` elements (e.g. `nav`) They're are a few other's too that won't save/or are just substituted by `<p></p>` once pasted uploaded to my hosting platfrom register365. Also empty `div` tags containing a `class=""` (which contains my image urls) goes missing as well. What's the reasoning behind this? How do I work around this error?

This is what empty `div` tags are getting replaced by `<p>&nbsp;</p>`
& `HTML5` tags `header`, `nav`, etc. are been displayed at all?

My questions are; 
Why is this happening, can I stop it?
And how do I work around the `HTML5` elements?

Comment: You can probably stop it by uploading your files directly. We can't help you if your CMS hates what you put into it... This is not an issue related to `html`, `html5` nor `css` - this is an issue of whatever CMS/upload system you are using/

Comment: @somethinghere it's a website with html & css only. And I'm using other software to code the html. I then upload it to the site and it displays incorrectly. When I go to edit these changes through the website's text editore (think it's tiny_mce) it leaves out html5 elements and changes div tags to <p>&nbsp</p>. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Should I use filezilla?

Comment: Then maybe using a tag like `tinyMCE` is more appropriate. TinyMCE however is notorious for converting things into whatever it finds appropriate. If you think you need to edit HTML, why not do that directly? Using FileZilla for file uploads is good, but most uploaders don't modify files. TinyMCE _does_ modify your inputs a lot. Have a look into ACE editor instead of tinyMCE ( http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about )

Comment: Thanks for this. But, how do I change it when it's the website register365.com that is hosting my website and the text editor?

Comment: If you have bought hosting with them, they should provide you with a way to simply connect using FTP and upload your own text files. If not, and you are using their wysiwyg editor, maybe you need a different package. I am not familiar with register365, so I can't tell. It is logical that in a Wysiwyg editor, things get converted to safer things (for example, your host would not allow inserting scripts into WYSIWYG). This one you will have to figure out for yourself, but look for FTP - that'll get you started.

Comment: Thanks a million, this really helped me! Going to get filezilla working

Comment: Good luck with all your future development :)